# How to sort nested object

Tags: mongodb

```
    db.sort.drop();
    db.sort.insert({stats: [{userId: 1, date: '01012013'},{userId: 2, date: '31122012'}]});
    db.sort.insert({stats: [{userId: 1, date: '31122013'},{userId: 2, date: '01012012'}]});

    > db.sort.find({'stats.userId': 1}).sort({'stats.date': 1}).pretty()
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52af1ce974be7dbd071e8563"),
            "stats" : [
                    {
                            "userId" : 1,
                            "date" : "31122013"
                    },
                    {
                            "userId" : 2,
                            "date" : "01012012"
                    }
            ]
    }
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52af1ce974be7dbd071e8562"),
            "stats" : [
                    {
                            "userId" : 1,
                            "date" : "01012013"
                    },
                    {
                            "userId" : 2,
                            "date" : "31122012"
                    }
            ]
    }
```

How to get the documents sorted by date userId: 1? 
I expect to see:

```
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52af1ce974be7dbd071e8562"),
            "stats" : [
                    {
                            "userId" : 1,
                            "date" : "01012013"
                    },
                    {
                            "userId" : 2,
                            "date" : "31122012"
                    }
            ]
    }

    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52af1ce974be7dbd071e8563"),
            "stats" : [
                    {
                            "userId" : 1,
                            "date" : "31122013"
                    },
                    {
                            "userId" : 2,
                            "date" : "01012012"
                    }
            ]
    }
```

Comment: WHat *output* are you expecting?

Comment: If you do the sorting by date, the document will be the first one in which the date of 01012012, but I expect to see the document with the date 01012013 as needed sorting by a specific user

Comment: Edited answer, I get your expected result

Comment: Alex I corrected the question

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of:

```
db.COLLECTION.find({stats.userID: 1}).sort({'stats.date':1})
```

Given your data above, when I execute that query, I get this back:

```
"stats" : [ 
    {
        "userId" : 1,
        "date" : 1012013
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But in this case will sort all dates, but I need only sort by userId date

Comment: It finds your documents by UserId, then sorts...? Where's the problem?

Comment: I updated the document. If you do sorting by date, the first document will be in the second place, because all the dates are sorted

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, please edit your question and post your expected output

Comment: You completely changed the structure of the data. Am out of ideas for now

Answer (score 0):

You could use the aggregation framework to achieve

```
db.sort.aggregate(
[
        {$unwind:"$stats"},
        {$match:{"stats.userId":1}},
        {$sort:{"stats.date":1}}
]);
```

If you could change your schema to store the user+id combination as the field name with the date as its value then you accomplish this easily

```
> db.so2.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "stats" : [
                {
                        "userId1" : "01012013"
                },
                {
                        "userId2" : "31122012"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "stats" : [
                {
                        "userId1" : "31122013"
                },
                {
                        "userId2" : "01012012"
                }
        ]
}
```

You then change the query predicate from userId : 1 to check for existence of the userId field

```
> db.so2.find({"stats.userId1":{$exists:1}}).sort({"stats.userId1":1}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "stats" : [
                {
                        "userId1" : "01012013"
                },
                {
                        "userId2" : "31122012"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "stats" : [
                {
                        "userId1" : "31122013"
                },
                {
                        "userId2" : "01012012"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment! But in this case, you can not configure indexes.

Comment: If you are using the alternate schema then you can index stats.userId1